# My logitech g602 extra button stopped working after ubuntu update

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, logitech

after a software update my Logitech g602 extra button stopped working after restarting still doesn't work? can someone help me fix the problem. I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: It's likely you mean Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS, but it's best if we're told.  Also which kernel stack you're using (GA or the 5.4 kernel, or 5.8 and the HWE stack) may also help.  If you select another (older) kernel at `grub` does it work?  (you've tagged *drivers*; kernel modules (*drivers*) relate to the kernel directly so knowing which stack you're using is needed as LTS releases offer two stacks/choices)

Comment: the kernel version i am using is  5.8.0-50-generic

Comment: just installed an old kernel 5.4 and the mouse worked but wifi stopped working

Comment: thanks for your help  @guiverc after kernel downgrade from 5.8.0-50 to 5.8.0-48 my Logitech g602 is working perfectly.